# Sql copying a data from table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a shopping cart project. I want to copy a data from table to another one but when i use this query

```
USE PRODUCTS 
SELECT NAME,PRICE,BOUGHT 
INTO CART 
FROM COMPUTERS
```

i can only copy 1 data and after the first run it says table already created. What i want to do is append the old table not try to creat a new one. Can you give me some ideas, queries maybe ?

Comment: Can you show us the table description of both tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into CART
(NAME,
PRICE,
BOUGHT)
select NAME, PRICE, BOUGHT from COMPUTERS
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
USE PRODUCTS 
SELECT NAME,PRICE,BOUGHT 
FROM COMPUTERS
INSERT INTO CART
```

Comment: No it is not working                                                              Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'CART'.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1.

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName
SELECT * FROM OldTableName
```

2.

```
INSERT INTO NewTableName (column1, column1)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM OldTableName
```

**Use 1st method if both tables have same schema.**

Comment: Thanks, i thought about that situations but i just didn't know the correct query to do it .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
DECLARE c CURSOR READ_ONLY     FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT nama,price,bought
FROM Computers

Declare @name nvarchar(50)
Declare @price nvarchar(50)
Declare @bought nvarchar(50)

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO   @name,@price,@bought
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Cart (name,price,bought)      values (@name,@price,@bought)

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @name,@price,@bought
END

CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```